# Squirrel and setting up drivers

Tags: jdbc, driver, squirrel-sql

I like SQuirreL, but I am having a hell of a time getting the driver set up!  I am trying to connect to a Intersystems Cache Database.  I have downloaded the CacheBD.jar file but SQuirreL continually gives me the error:

Could not find class CacheBD in neither the Java class path nor the Extra class path of the Intersystems Cache driver definition:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: CacheBD

I have put the jar file in several places, added a CLASSPATH variable, and I can not get it to work...irky.

Can someone please give a step by steb for dummies guide to installing and adding a driver to SQuirreL?

Thanks for any guidance.

Leslie

Answer (score 0):

I needed to select the 5.2_CacheDB jar instead..once I did that the correct Class Name was populated in the driver set up and it turned green.